# ASP VBscript get sql script of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, vbscript

With microsoft sql server manager i know how to get this problem solved, but on the hosting where i am trying to update a old ASP Vbscript website i dont have access to this manager. and my question is:
Is possible from ASP VBscript environement to access a stored procedure sql script ? and to see what sql queries were used for this stored procedure ?
I know how to show their names but also i am interested in their content to know what tables do not touch with my modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [nice little tutorial example](http://weblogs.asp.net/cumpsd/archive/2006/10/18/681812.aspx)

First, show all the stored procedures in the database:

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'P' AND category = 0 ORDER BY name
```

Next, retrieve a stored procedure's contents :

```
SELECT text 
FROM syscomments 
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE name = '{0}') 
ORDER BY colid
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run a query like this:

```
SELECT definition 
    FROM sys.sql_modules 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourProcedureName')
```

Comment: Joe thanks for your response but in my DB i dont have this table sys.sql_modules.

Comment: @Constantine: I should have asked what version of SQL Server. You must be using 2000 or earlier?

Comment: i am not sure, it should be close to SQL Server 2000, because website was built before 2005